# With what else can I fill a water pillow, as it seeps water?

Tags: sleeping

After being washed in the machine last week and  air-dried, my 4-year-old water pillow started to ooze water, as the cover quickly turns humid. I haven't been able to pinpoint the leak.

Rather than discarding it, what else I can fill it with? I'm thinking of [small beads](https://www.google.com/search?q=small+beads&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj16erR4qDfAhULrYMKHa3xDTwQ_AUIDigB&biw=891&bih=525).

Comment: Polystyrene balls, like some travel pillows? Fine powder like cornflour? Are you particularly averse to replacing the pillow (in struggling to see the sense in retaining it; as a non leaking water pillow it makes sense but as a leaking one filled with something else it would seem to be just a pillow case, and hence of little intrinsic value in the face of other pillow cases.. perhaps filling it with a dyed water would help pinpoint the leaks

Comment: @CaiusJard "perhaps filling it with a dyed water would help pinpoint the leaks": Great idea! But even if I pinpoint the leaks, can I seal the leaks?

Comment: Depends what it's made of; I'd imagine most things are repairable, so long as the correct patch is applied

Comment: (PlastiDip may work)

Comment: maybe try to fix it using a fix-a-flat or other tire-based sealer, just let it dry before re-filling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that any substitute filler will feel quite like water. I know this doesn't directly answer the question but perhaps you can pinpoint the leak by blowing the pillow up with air, fill a bathtub with water, submerge the pillow and squeeze lightly until you see where the bubbles are coming from. When you find where it is you can patch it up. You may then be able to seal the leak by pinching it and blowing a hot hair dryer on the hole so that it will melt back together. Another option would be Goop. (http://eclecticproducts.com/products/amazing-goop-adhesives/)